# How to get a queryset from many to many field

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

I have this model and i want to retrieve all the "members" as queryset

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='owner')
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='members') # <---
```

I tried this but its not working

```
Team.objects.all()['members'] # and
Team.members.all()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind i just found that i need to first filter the model and then access "members"

```
team = Team.objects.filter(belonging=group)
members = team.members.all()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
team_object = Team.objects.first()
members = team_object.members.all()
```

This will get you all the members related to the team_object